# Is there any need of log table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench

I am developing an application that has database of mysql having orders and orderdetails table. order table having column orderStatus. My question is whether it is necessary to create another order log table if order status is 'closed' (that means completed orders) or just orderstatus column is enough.

Comment: what is your criteria for "necessary"? Obviously both can work. The full range of queries needs to be examined to look at the complexity of all of them. If you are unsure of these, just pick a method, the simplest one. As you develop you application you'll start to see if it was a bad choice or not, at which you can change, or call it software debt.

Comment: @danblack thank you